# Getting contour levels in BarLegend to match their tick location instead of being equally spaced

Tags: plotting, legending

Currently, I have the following

```
BarLegend[{colourScheme, {0, 10}}, {0.1, 5, 5.5}]
```

[image]

The contours are evenly distributed across the colourbar. I want them to sit where the corresponding tick values are (so 0.1 should be very close to the bottom, 5 should be right in the middle, etc.). How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. What is the value at the top of the scale? Is this a compressed scale of some kind? Why is `5` sitting right in the middle? What is `colourScheme`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

The following provides what appears to be requested.

```
BarChart[{10, 5.5, 5, 0.1}, ChartLayout -> "Overlapped", 
    ImageSize -> Tiny, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 4, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ChartLabels -> 
    Placed[{"10.", "5.5", "5.0", "0.1"}, {{1, 1}, {-.5, .5}}]]
```

[image]

If eliminating the top label is desired, replace `"10."` by `Null`.  Colors can be changed by replacing `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"` by a custom `ChartStyle`, for instance `ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Cyan, Purple}`.

[image]

Comment: That does the trick. Quite surprising Mathematica doesn't have an inbuilt option to do this, but alas. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[contourLegend]
```

The function `contourLegend` takes `Graphics` options and options to control ticks, tick labels and legend orientation:

```
Options[contourLegend] = Join[
   {"Ticks" -> Automatic, 
    "TickLabels" -> Automatic, 
    "TickLengths" -> Automatic, 
    "TickSide" -> Right, 
    "TickDirection" -> "Out", 
    "RotateLabel" -> False, 
    "Appearance" -> "Vertical"},
  Options[Graphics]];
```

The first two arguments specify the color scheme and contour levels, which are used to construct rectangles with appropriate colors.

```
contourLegend[{cs_, range_ : {0, 1}}, contours_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{$rects, $ticks, $tvals, $tlbls, $tlngths, $rot,
   $cl = Join[{range[[1]]}, contours, {range[[2]]}],
   $wdth = -Subtract @@ range /15,
   $tr = OptionValue["Appearance"] /.
      {Automatic | "Vertical" | "Column" -> Identity, _ -> Reverse},
   $tr2 = OptionValue["TickSide"] /. 
      {Right | After | Above | Top | Automatic -> Identity, _ -> Reverse},
   $clrs = ColorData[{cs, range}] /@ 
     Join[{range[[1]]}, MovingAverage[contours, 2], {range[[2]]}]},
  $tvals = OptionValue["Ticks"] /. Automatic -> $cl;
  $tlbls = OptionValue["TickLabels"] /. Automatic -> $tvals;
  $rot = OptionValue["RotateLabel"] /. 
     {False -> 0  Degree, True -> 90  Degree, x_ :> x};
  $tlbls = Map[Rotate[#, $rot] &] @ $tlbls;
  $tlngths = OptionValue["TickLengths"] /. Automatic -> 
     (OptionValue["Appearance"] /. 
          {Automatic|"Vertical"|"Column" -> .15, _ -> .015});
  $tlngths = If[ListQ @ OptionValue["TickLengths"], $tlngths, 
    OptionValue["TickDirection"] /. 
     {"In" -> {$tlngths, 0}, "InOut" -> $tlngths {1, 1}, _ -> {0, $tlngths}}];
  $rects = Map[Rectangle @@ Transpose[$tr@{{0, $wdth}, #}] &] @ 
     Partition[$cl, 2, 1];
  $ticks = Thread[{$tvals, $tlbls, $tlngths}, List, 2];
  Graphics[MapThread[{EdgeForm[], #, #2} &] @ {$clrs, $rects}, 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]],
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> {{50, All}, All},
   ImagePadding -> All,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> $tr @ {$tr2 @ {None, $ticks}, {None, None}}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{contourLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, {.2, .6, .7, .9}],
   contourLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 10}}, {2, 6, 7, 9}],
   contourLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}, {.2, .6, .7, .9}],
   contourLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 100}}, {10, 30, 50, 90}],
   contourLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 100}}, {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "Ticks" -> {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "TickLabels" -> {"A", "BBBB", "CC", "label 4"}, 
    FrameLabel -> {{Style["legend", 18], None}, {None, None}}],
   contourLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 100}}, {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "Ticks" -> {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "TickLabels" -> {"A", "BBBB", "CC", "label 4"}, 
    "TickSide" -> Left, "TickDirection" -> "InOut", 
    "TickLengths" -> .25, FrameTicksStyle -> Thick, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["legend", 16]]
   }, Spacer[20]] // Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] &
```

[image]

```
Column[{contourLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, {.2, .6, .7, .9}, 
    "Appearance" -> "Horizontal"],
   contourLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 10}}, {2, 6, 7, 9}, 
    "Appearance" -> "Horizontal"],
   contourLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}, {.2, .6, .7, .9}, 
    "Appearance" -> "Horizontal"],
   contourLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 100}}, {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "Appearance" -> "Horizontal"],
   contourLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 100}}, {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "Ticks" -> {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "TickLabels" -> {"A", "BBBB", "CC", "label 4"}, 
    "Appearance" -> "Horizontal", "RotateLabel" -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {Style["legend", 18], None}}],
   contourLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 100}}, {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "Ticks" -> {10, 30, 50, 90}, 
    "TickLabels" -> {"A", "BBBB", "CC", "label 4"}, 
    "TickSide" -> Left, "TickDirection" -> "InOut", 
    "TickLengths" -> .025, "Appearance" -> "Horizontal", 
    "RotateLabel" -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> Thick, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["legend", 16]]
   }, Dividers -> All] // Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] &
```

[image]

```
With[{contours = {-1., -.8, .5, 1.25}}, 
 ContourPlot[2 Sin[x  y], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> contours, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotLegends -> contourLegend[{"Rainbow", {-2, 2}}, contours]]]
```

[image]

```
With[{contours = {-1., -.8, .5, 1.25}}, 
 ContourPlot[2  Sin[x   y], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> contours, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
     contourLegend[{"Rainbow", {-2, 2}}, contours, 
      "Appearance" -> Row, ImageSize -> {250, 50}, "RotateLabel" -> True], 
     Top]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the second argument is specified, `BarLegend` produces equally-spaced contours with shading determined by the value of color function at specified contour levels.

To get a bar legend that *behaves* like `ContourPlot` (that is, shaded areas are proportional to differences between successive contour values) we can use (what else?) `ContourPlot` as follows:

```
barLegend[{cs_, range_: Automatic}, contours_, ticks_ : Automatic,
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{rmin = First[range /. Automatic -> {0, 1}], 
   rmax = Last[range /. Automatic -> {0, 1}]}, 
  ContourPlot[$y, {$x, 0, 1}, {$y, rmin, rmax}, opts, 
   ColorFunction -> cs, Contours -> contours, 
   AspectRatio -> (rmax - rmin), PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, ContourStyle -> None, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, {#, #, {0, .1}} & /@ (ticks /. 
         Automatic -> Join[{rmin}, contours, {rmax}])}, {None, None}}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 10}}, {0.1, 5, 5.5}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 400], 
  barLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 10}}, 
   {0.1, 5, 5.5}, 
   {0.1, 5, 5.5, 10}, 
   ContourStyle -> None,
   ImageSize -> {100, 400}, 
   AspectRatio -> 20, 
   LabelStyle -> 14]}, 
  Spacer[30]]
```

[image]

Replace `"Rainbow"` with `"TemperatureMap"` to get

[image]

```
With[{contours = {-.8, -.9, 1, .75}},
 Row[ContourPlot[Sin[x  y], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, 
     ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> contours, 
     ImageSize -> 300, PlotLegends -> #] & /@
   {Automatic, 
    barLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, contours, AspectRatio -> 20, 
     ImageSize -> {80, 300}, ImagePadding -> All]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The barLegend function doesn't seem to work. The output just prints `barLegend({"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}, {-0.8, -0.9, 1, 0.75}, 
 AspectRatio -> 20, ImageSize -> {80, 300}, ImagePadding -> All)`.

Comment: Thank you @Sharplie12321. I updated with a correction - replaced `range:Automatic`  with  `range_:Automatic`.